# Using Automator to obtain content from multiple webpages?

Tags: safari, automator

I'd like to use Apple's Automator to obtain content from multiple webpages. The webpages each contain links, text, and photos. I would then like to place this information in a text document.

Detailed steps would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Automator, as an automation tool, is a bit of a sledgehammer, so the following is a bit clumsy, but works.

Automator provides two actions for choosing URLs: **Get Specified URLs**, that allows one to specify a pre-determined list of URLs, and **Get Current Webpage from Safari**, that specifies the URL of Safari's current webpage. It also provides three nice actions for parsing we webpages: **Get Text from Webpage**, **Get Image URLs from Webpage** and **Get Link URLs from Webpages**, which do what you would expect them to. Finally, Automator provides an action to place text in a document: **Set Contents of TextEdit Document**. You may also want to use the **Get Specified Text** action to separate the text, images, and links sections of your new TextEdit Document.

Here is what your complete Automator workflow might look like:

**Get Specified Text** `--- Text of Webpage ---`

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by replacing" option.

**Get Current Webpage from Safari**

**Get Text from Webpage**

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by *appending*" option.

**Get Specified Text** `--- Images URLs of Webpage ---`

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by appending" option.

**Get Current Webpage from Safari**

**Get Image URLs from Webpage**

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by appending" option.

**Get Specified Text** `--- Link URLs of Webpage ---`

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by appending" option.

**Get Current Webpage from Safari**

**Get Link URLs from Webpages**

**Set Contents of TextEdit Document** using the "by appending" option.

When this workflow finishes, there will be a new untitled TextEdit document open whose contents is text, image URLs and link URLs of Safari's current webpage. You can save it wherever you please.